# Jquery mobile: Detect if it is the user's first launch of the app

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hi Iam trying to detect if the user is launching my app for the first time with this code. But in the `$(document).on('pageshow','#welcome-page', function(){` part, my variable `firstlaunch` is always undefined. Can you help me figure out what to do ?

Thanks

```
var firstlaunch;


$(function(firstlaunch) {
    firstlaunch = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("firstlaunch"));
    //store 0 for next time
    if ( firstlaunch == null || typeof firstlaunch == 'undefined' || isNaN(firstlaunch) ) {     
        firstlaunch = 1;
        window.localStorage.setItem("firstlaunch", 0);
    }
});

$(document).on('pageshow','#welcome-page', function(){

console.log("firstlaunch pageshow #welcome-page = "+firstlaunch);
console.log("typeof firstlaunch pageshow #welcome-page = "+typeof firstlaunch);
  if ( firstlaunch ==1 || typeof firstlaunch == 'undefined' || isNaN(firstlaunch) ){
               //do things if first visit
        } else if (firstlaunch == 0) {
              //do things if not first visit
        } else {
            console.log('Error :  firstlaunch ='+firstlaunch);
        }

});
```

Comment: it's easier to use `!!` to check the var isn't `null` nor `undefined` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pjDac/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/d4rTr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you all.
I went with the solution of @ezanker because it was close to my code and simple.
Thank you again.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#welcome-page", function(){
    alert(IsFirstLaunch());
});

function IsFirstLaunch(){
    var fl = window.localStorage.getItem("firstlaunch");
    if (fl && parseInt(fl) == 0){
        return false;
    } else {        
        window.localStorage.setItem("firstlaunch", "0");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `localStorage.getItem()` call will return null if it does not exist.

The simplest way to do this would be like this:

```
$(document).one('pageshow','#welcome-page', function(){
    var noRunCount = (localStorage.getItem("runCount") == null);
    if (noRunCount) {
        // You know it's the first time this is run because 
        // the variable isn't even defined yet
        localStorage.setItem("runCount", 1);
    } else {
        // The variable exists, so it must have been set by your app
        localStorage.setItem("runCount", (localStorage.getItem("runCount") + 1));
    }
}
```

One thing to note here is the use of `$(document).one('pageshow', )` instead of `$(document).on('pageshow', )`.  This makes the logic in this block only execute the first time the welcome page is loaded.